# "The day of February 20, 1909 fell on a Saturday." Should I use "a" in front of Saturday or not?

Tags: articles

Should I use "a" in front of Saturday or not?

> The day of February 20, 1909 fell on **a** Saturday.

Comment: You should - but you could usefully shorten the sentence to read: *February 20, 1909 fell on a Saturday*. When you say *on Saturday* - without the article - you usually refer to either last Saturday (I saw them on Saturday) or next Saturday (I will see them on Saturday).

Answer (score 4):

You should keep the indefinite article there. It means you merely wish to express what day of the week that date fell on.

> February 20, 1909 fell on a Saturday.

(Note that you don't need "The day of" unless you are trying to sound dramatic.)

You would only drop the article if the date fell on the *latest* Saturday. For example,

> February 4, 2017 fell on Saturday.

Which it did this year. This sentence is good until February 11. If you want to refer to next Saturday, you can say

> February 11, 2017 falls on Saturday.

This sentence is also good until February 11 this year.

Note that either of the latter sentences can also use an article if you are concerned merely with what day of the week the date falls on in general.

Comment: I think you overstate the case for including the article. I see nothing unusual about saying *Next Christmas falls on Monday* without the article, at any point in the year. Whilst it's true that the standalone statement *My birthday is on Monday* would always be taken to mean the first Monday after time of utterance, I'd be fine with *My birthday is on Monday this year* even if said Monday is many months in the future.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, now you're changing the sentence. The one given by the OP did not include "this year" and you can't say "My birthday is on Monday" if you don't add "this year" (unless you really mean the coming Monday).

Comment: I mean to say "this year" or another time expression ("next year" or "in five years" or "in 2020" or the like).

Comment: Well, it seems to me that including the article in *[some event] **fell/falls/will fall** on **a** [dayofweek]* almost always *excludes* the possibility that you're specifically referring to the most recent or next occurrence of that day. But I just don't really buy the converse (that *not* including the article always limits the the referent in that way). I've no doubt it's more common to include it in, say, *If [event] fell on **a** Sunday* - but I don't reject *If it fell on Sunday*, nor do I think that automatically means *If it happened **last** Sunday* unless context so dictates.

Comment: So your idiosyncrasies are now ... evidence?

Answer (score 1):

> February 20, 1909 fell on a Saturday.

is correct and understandable, you use the indefinite article "a" to specify one of many Saturdays (there are 52 in a year), if you wanted to reference a particular Saturday, you might say

> February 20, 1909 fell on *the* Saturday after Valentine's Day.

since there is a unique Saturday that is directly after Valentine's Day that is possible.